# typedef with a forward declaration side-effect?

Tags: c, typedef, forward-declaration

I have the following declaration in a header file:

```
struct my_struct;
int func(struct my_struct* s);        // Passing struct my_struct*
```

Without the forward declaration, the compiler would obviously give [this error](http://ideone.com/foyNM):

> `error: 'struct my_struct' declared inside parameter list`

However, if I replace the forward declaration of `my_struct` with a typedef, and update the function declaration accordingly, it [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/loENi):

```
typedef struct my_struct my_struct_t;
int func(mystruct_t* s);              // Passing my_struct_t*
```

Curiously, if I keep the typedef, but use the original declaration `my_struct`, it [also compiles](http://ideone.com/UoTLb):

```
typedef struct my_struct my_struct_t;
int func(struct my_struct* s);        // Passing struct my_struct*
```

Did anybody else notice that? Is that behavior a side-effect?

Comment: The typedef acts as a forward declaration too, it brings the type name into scope.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I've noticed that :) but I couldn't find anything in the standard stating that. Did I miss something?

Comment: There is no need for a forward declaration to create a pointer to a structure. It is just a convention. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ghasan you are wrong. You can't use a pointer to a structure without declaring its name.

Comment: @Riateche This is odd, but when I declare a variable such as "struct id *p;" without any forward declaration, it compiles without error using "-Wall -ansi -pedantic".

Comment: @Ghasan You can, but not in a function parameter list. See [link](http://ideone.com/BmrjE).

Comment: @EitanT Great! Now I know why. If it were allowed no one would be able to use it, because it would only declare the pointer and go out of scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In section 6.2.1, paragraph 7:

> Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just after the appearance of
>   the tag in a type speciﬁer that declares the tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that
>   begins just after the appearance of its deﬁning enumerator in an enumerator list. Any
>   other identiﬁer has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator.

And in 6.7.2.3, paragraph 8:

> If a type speciﬁer of the form
>   struct-or-union identiﬁer
>   occurs other than as part of one of the above forms, and no other declaration of the
>   identiﬁer as a tag is visible, then it declares an incomplete structure or union type, and
>   declares the identiﬁer as the tag of that type.

The `typedef` thus declares an incomplete structure type.